# Template function instantiation file?

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

I have created instantiation files for classes before, but I am curious has to how I would create one for just a function. Here's an example of a program I made.

```
template <typename T>
void deSelSort(T arr[], int n)
{
int j = n - 1;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

for(int i = 0; i < j; i++, j--) {

    int min=i;
    int max=i;
    int temp;

    for (int temp2 = i + 1; temp2 <= j; temp2++)
    {
        if (arr[temp2] < arr[min]) 
            { 
                min = temp2; 
            }
        if (arr[temp2] > arr[max]) 
            { 
                max = temp2; 
            }
    }

    if (min > max) { 
        temp=min; 
        min=max; 
        max=temp;
        arr[min] = max; 
        arr[max] = min;
    }
    if (min > i) 
    { 
        temp = arr[i]; 
        arr[i] = arr[min];
        arr[min] = temp; 
    }
    if (max < j) 
    { 
        temp = arr[j]; 
        arr[j] = arr[max];
        arr[max] = temp; 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;


};
}
```

What would the instantiation file look like if I wanted to create an array with ints and doubles for example? Right now my file looks like this

```
#include "ex3_16.cpp"

template class deSelSort<int>;
template class deSelSort<double>;
```

Comment: `template void deSelSort<int>(int[], int);` and `template void deSelSort<double>(double[], int);`

Answer (score 1):

> What would the instantiation file look like if I wanted to create an array with `ints` and `doubles` for example?

```
template void deSelSort<int>(int[], int);
template void deSelSort<double>(double[], int);
```